# Offsetting Objects Along a Curve Perpendicular to the Curve Geometry Nodes

Tags: node-editor, bezier-curves, geometry

I have an objects along a curve geometry nodes setup and I would like to randomly offset the objects perpendicular to the curve without effecting the Z axis...I guess you could say scattering along a curve (as shown in the mockup example). I am able to offset the objects randomly along the curve (based on tutorials), but don't know how to eliminate / suppress the Z axis offset. If possible could someone please show me the node setup.
[image]
Here's my node setup so far. I did not include the random offset I tried in this setup.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by reverse engineering an addon I have, played around with it until it worked.

Here is the whole node setup.
[image]

Here is a closeup of the nodes.
[image]

Here it is working.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

before your instance on points node, you can use this node setup here:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Chris, I'll give that a go.